# create email link from JS

Tags: javascript, html, email

In Java Script have this expression that returns an email address:

```
calendarMonth[i].events[j].email
```

I want to create an html link so with after clicking in this email a person will open an email like outlook. I am trying to use this model

```
<a href="mailto:email@echoecho.com?subject=SweetWords">
Send Email</a>
```

but I am having lots of problem with the assembling of the html code using JS. I was trying

```
var email = '<b>Email: </b>'+ ' <a href="mailto:'+ 
calendarMonth[i].events[j].email+'"> <br/>';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: SO you need a mailTo link

Comment: You're missing `Send Email</a>` in your code.

Comment: @epascarello He knows that, it's in the question. You just couldn't see it because he didn't format the code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is right, you just messed up the HTML syntax. You're missing the contents of the anchor and the `</a>` closing tag.

```
var email = '<b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:' + calendarMonth[i].events[j].email + '">' + 
            calendarMonth[i].events[j].email + '</a>';
```